# Laravel, whereHas with belongsToMany relationship not working properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have table a "tasks" with self referencing. I need to use whereHas method from Eloquent. First, I used just parent_id column in the same table, but I was getting empty model. I have read that this is a [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4754) and was fixed just in Laravel 5. In this case, I created I pivot table, "task_dependency", with two columns: "task_id" and "parent_id".
These are the realtionships in the Task Model

```
public function parent()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Task', 'task_dependency', 'task_id', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Task', 'task_dependency', 'parent_id', 'task_id');
}
```

But I didn't get rid of all problems. 
This code:

```
Task::whereHas('parent', function($q) {
    $q->where('status', 4);
})
```

generates the below query:

```
select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`deleted_at` is null and 
(select count(*) from `task_dependency` as 
`self_25523d38deca8ac023c5241dc6c5de6e` where 
`self_25523d38deca8ac023c5241dc6c5de6e`.`task_id` = `tasks`.`id` and 
`status` = '4' and `tasks`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1
```

Which doesn't return the corect results. It returns no rows, even if the parent task has status 4.
How can I rezolve this problem? Thank you.